# Python - Scrabble_score

Tags: python

Can someone break down the individual components that make up scrabble_score:

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
    "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
    "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
    "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
    "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    return sum([score[x] for x in word.replace(" ", "").lower() if x in score])
```

Comment: its list comprehension passed to sum with dict lookup on each letter to know the score

Comment: Please provide more details regarding what is the expected result, and what is that you are having hard time with.

Comment: Expected result is for a word to return a certain score - like scrabble.


I was working on something like:

    `def scrabble_score(word):
    result = 0
    print(word)
    for c in word:
        for value in score:
            if c == value:
                result += sum(score.values())
    return result
`
#iterate through all chars in the word, then iterate through the keys in score, if the key matched the char it would add the value of that key to result ^ my code does not work but it seems(to me) like reasonably sound logic?

Answer (score 1):

The structure is a list comprehension. This is a terse way of creating a list from an iterable. See below where the `1`s are list comps and the `2`s are traditional `for` loops.

```
result1 = [some_value for element in iterable]
# where the group of "value" statements is the final list

result2 = []
for element in iterable:
    result2.append(some_value)

example1 = [x**2 for x in range(10)]  #  [0**2, 1**2, 2**2, ..., 9**2]
example2 = []
for x in range(10):
    example2.append(x)
```

This particular listcomp is using a dict lookup (`score[x]`) as the value of the list, where `x` is each element of `word.replace(" ", "").lower()`. It also uses a conditional filtering statement at the end to make sure it only selects those elements where `x` is in `score` (so something like `it's` doesn't fail on the `'`.)

Wrapped around it is `sum`, which simply adds all the numbers in a list and gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

broken down (in bold)...

`return sum([score[x] for x in word.replace(" ", "").lower() if x in score])`

removes all spaces and converts to all lower case

`return sum([score[x] for x in word.replace(" ", "").lower() if x in score])`

for each letter after removing spaces and converting to lower case

`return sum([score[x] for x in word.replace(" ", "").lower() if x in score])`

if that letter is in the score dictionary

`return sum([score[x] for x in word.replace(" ", "").lower() if x in score])`

get the score for that letter and add it to a list

`return sum([score[x] for x in word.replace(" ", "").lower() if x in score])`

after getting the score for each letter, add up the sum of the resulting list of values and return

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. I guess now I'm having trouble in understanding what order the elements are ordered in. As a sentence it makes sense, but in python it seems so jumbled with so little code doing so many actions...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for solution

total_score variable is to sum letter score. 
the score[char.lower()] is for code that will work even if the letters you get are uppercase, lowercase, or a mix

```
 def scrabble_score (word):
  total_score=0
  for char in word:
    total_score+=score[char.lower()]
  return total_score
```